# Java synchronized blocks -- lock objects

Tags: java, synchronized

In the sample code

```
public class MsLunch {
private long c1 = 0;
private long c2 = 0;
private Object lock1 = new Object();
private Object lock2 = new Object();

public void inc1() {
    synchronized(lock1) {
        c1++;
    }
}

public void inc2() {
    synchronized(lock2) {
        c2++;
    }
}
}
```

on [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) page,

**lock1** and **lock2** are controlling the updates on **c1** and **c2** resply.

However,

```
    synchronized(lock2)
```

is acquiring the lock of the object **lock1** and releasing it when the synchronized block

```
    synchronized(lock1) {
        c1++;
    }
```

is executed.

While this block is being executed, there may be 
an update on member **c1** of **this** object still-- and I don't 
see how this update is being prevented by 
synchronizing on **lock1** as in the code.

It is the object **lock1** that there is exclusive access on-- 
and nothing else(?)

So, how is the implementation

```
public void inc1() {
    synchronized(lock1) {
        c1++;
    }
}
```

in the above code different from

```
public void synchronized inc1() {
        c1++;
}
```

or even

```
public void inc1() {
    synchronized(c1) {
        //do something on c1
    }
}
```

when **c1** is an object but not a primitive?

What am I missing here ?

Note: I saw

[What is the difference between synchronized on lockObject and using this as the lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369287/synchronized-block-lock-object-question)

and

[Java synchronized method lock on object, or method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047564/java-synchronized-method-lock-on-object-or-method)

among some other discussions.

Comment: Why do you believe that `synchronized(lock2)` is locking on `lock1`?

Comment: @chrylis - read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Comment: I'm familiar with the concurrency docs and just read that page. It doesn't say anywhere that `synchronized(lock2)` locks on `lock1`, because it doesn't.

Comment: thats generally how the synchronizing the blocks work-- synchronize(someStuff) acquires the lock of someStuff and thus noone else can access to someStuff till the thread finished executing that block. read the page.

Comment: @Roam: No, you are wrong. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Implementation 1.**

You are locking on the `lock1` object.  Nothing else that needs a lock on `lock1` can execute. Having your two methods lock on different objects means that the two methods can run concurrently, but no two threads can run the same method concurrently.

**Implementation 2.**

Making a method `synchronized` means that the entire method body is implicitly in a `synchronized(this)` block (or synchronized on the `Class` object if the method is `static`.  If both methods are `synchronized`, then one method would prevent the other from running at the same time, which is different then locking both methods on different objects.

**Implementation 3.**

If `c1` is an object and not a primitive, then the semantics are very similar to implementation 1 - locking on an explicit object.

Comment: as far as i see, your first par. verifies what i'm saying. so, what's the point in that implementation? the lock of lock1 is acquired only and c1 is still in the "loose". how does "Implementation 1"-- the way you stated in your ans. differ from "Implementation 2"?

Comment: The difference comes in when you have multiple locks - Implementation 1 allows one thread to lock on `lock1`, but another thread is able to lock on `lock2`.  It is also possible for two threads to deadlock here - if thread "A" owns `lock1` and thread "B" owns `lock2`, but then thread "A" wants to lock `lock2` and thread "B" wants to lock `lock1`.  In implementation 2, there is only 1 lock, so a deadlock is not possible here.  But a thread can't execute one `synchronized` method if the other `synchronized` method is being executed; the lock is being held.

Comment: In this case, i can have another method 

 public void decr1() {  c1--; }

in the same class. so in this case, 
decr1() can execute and update 
c1 while incr1 is being run by some other thread (?) 
since it's lock1 that is locked, not c1. ami not right?

Comment: If you were to add a `decr1` method operating on `c1`, then have it lock on `lock1` (the same lock object that `incr1` uses), so two threads can't be updating `c1` at the same time, with either method.

Comment: thx for the useful answer. explains the intent of lock1/lock2.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is as far as I know incorrect. The page you linked doesn't state what you claim in your question neither. This is how locks work: Locks do *not* prevent threads of accessing an object at all. Locks only prevents **another thread of acquiring the same lock** while another thread already has acquired that lock.

This means that this can happen:

```
Thread A: synchronize (lockObject)
Thread B: lockObject.toString();
Thread A: release the lock on lockObject
```

This is what happens when two Threads want the same lock at the same time:

```
Thread A: synchronize (lockObject)
Thread B: synchronize (lockObject) // This will block until (1) !
Thread A: do some stuff and then release lock on lockObject
Thread B: gets the lock (1)
```

However:

```
public void synchronized inc1() {
    c1++;
}
```

is exactly the same as:

```
public void inc1() {
    synchronized(this) {
        c1++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, they are the same.  This means that in a given object instance, all code that is synchronized (blocks or keywords on methods) lock on the same lock object.  If that's not what you want/need, use different lock objects as arguments to synchronized blocks.

Comment: @Roam: The facts of what he wrote are correct, though the original phrasing left a bit to be desired.

Comment: My answer isn't bogus at all. I'm just telling you the truth. :)

Comment: I think I'll leave my answer as-is right now. So feel free to read :) I know, "a lie" was maybe a bad choice of word and was definitely not meant as a personal attack, but more as a general truth.

Comment: While reading your comments to other questions, I think you still do not fully understand the first part of what I wrote. Here is another attempt to clarify: Using synchronized blocks **only** affects behavior of other synchronized blocks (and really nothing else). That is the key to hold while programming multi-threaded applications. Synchronized code does not prevent other non-synchronized code of executing or accessing locked objects.

Comment: @Roam At First, Learn some basic manners to respect the volunteers., before learning the technical things.

Answer (score 0):

Marking a block or method `synchronized` without specifying a lock object synchronizes on the object who owns the method; in this case, the `MsLunch` instance. It's equivalent to `synchronized(this)`. The purpose of the lock-object idiom is to break that lock up so that `c1` and `c2` can be manipulated separately. A `synchronized` block can only synchronize on an object, not a primitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
synchronized(lock2){
  // do sth
}
```

is actually acquiring lock of object lock2

where as

```
public void synchronized inc1() {
        c1++;
}
```

acquires object on this object.

locks acquired by synchronized will be released once the program leaves the block.

Comment: well, thats fine. so what's the point in the implementation on page http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with one thread hogging the lock

```
for(;;){synchronized(lockObject){
...
}}
```

I guess Java doesn't like to unlock it on its own the first chance it gets.

Using an java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock fixed the problem

```
static ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
for(;;){
  lock.lock();
  ...
  lock.unlock();
}
```