# Using synchronized in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized-block

What's the difference between:

```
public synchronized void test(){}
```

and

```
public void test() {
   synchronized(Sample.class){}
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Synchronized block lock object question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369287/synchronized-block-lock-object-question)

Answer (score 5):

To make the difference more clear, the first can be rewritten as:

```
public void test() {    
   synchronized(this){    
   }    
}
```

The difference is that the first is synchronized on the *instance* of the class, whereas the second is synchronized on the *class itself*.

In the first case, two threads can simultaneously be executing `test()` on two instances of your class. In the second, they can't.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a an instance method `synchronized` is just syntactic sugar that's equivalent to having a `synchronized (this)` block. In other words, only a single thread can execute the method **on this instance** at a single point of time.

`synchronized (Sample.class)` means that all instances of this class share a single lock object (the class object itself), and only a single thread can execute this method **on any instance** at a single point in time.

Answer (score 1):

To complete @NPE's answer -

a `synchronized` method is actually a method that is `synchronized` on the object the method "belongs" to. Whether it's an instance object or the class object itself.

Therefore:

```
class Sample {
    public synchronized void test(){}
}
```

is equivalent to

```
class Sample {
    public void test() {
        synchronized(this) {}
    }
}
```

while

```
class Sample {
    public void test() {
       synchronized(Sample.class){}
    }
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
class Sample {
    public static synchronized void test(){}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But why static?

Comment: When you synchronize on the `Sample.class` object from within the `Sample` class, it's the same as synchronizing a static method in the `Sample` class. That's the point of my answer - a `synchronized` method is actually a method that is `synchronized` on the object the method "belongs" to. Whether it's an instance object or the class object itself. Are you familiar with the `static` concept?