# synchronized block : "expression expected"

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, concurrency

When I use the code shown below, IntelliJ IDEA tell me "expression expected" in the code `DecibelSample`. What is that mean, How can I fix it?

```
if (mDecibelSample == null) {
    synchronized (DecibelSample) { // expression expected
        if (mDecibelSample == null) {
            mDecibelSample = new DecibelSample();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `DecibelSample` is a class, this is not valid Java code.

Modify your code like this in order to get rid of the compile error:

```
synchronized (DecibelSample.class) {}
```

Your code won't work because `synchronized` needs some instance to lock against. In the modified example above it will use the `Class` instance.

You could also change it to `synchronized (this) {}` in which case it would use the instance of the class your method is in as the lock.

Third option is to define arbitrary object to use as a lock, for instance like this:

```
private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

...

public void foo() {
    synchronized(LOCK) {}
}
```

This would probably be the best approach, since locking against the current instance or class instance has some disadvantages. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3369303/1291150) for more details:

More information about the `synchronized` keyword can be found in [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19).

Answer (score 1):

The `synchronized` keyword requires an Object. `DecibelSample` is a classname, not an Object.

The Object will be used to ensure synchronization : i.e. when a thread need to execute the code inside the synchronized block : the thread must acquire a lock on the Object.

- if the lock can be aquired by the thread then the code inside the block is executed and the lock is released so that another thread can acquire it.
- if the lock cannot be acquired : the thread wait until the lock (owned by another thread) is released.

In your case, you need an Object to support the locking mechanism:

```
//used for locking only
// don't consume useless memory : a zero-sized array is fine
// ensure that the LOCK is shared between all threads : let's make it static
// ensure that the object used for locking cannot be changed by anyone : let's make it final
// at first sight : we don't need to synchronize on this Object in another class : keep it private.
private static final Object[] LOCK = new Object[0];

  ...
    if (mDecibelSample == null) {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            if (mDecibelSample == null) {
                mDecibelSample = new DecibelSample();
            }
        }
    }
```