# Run update operation in thread only if it isn't already running

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I need to do an update operation asynchronously when I receive a notification. The `update()` method below manipulates instance variables.

```
    public class UpdateOperation implements Runnable
    {
        private Boolean isInProgress = false;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try 
            {
                synchronized (isInProgress)
                {
                    isInProgress = true;
                }
                update(); //perform update
                synchronized (isInProgress)
                {
                    isInProgress = false;
                }
            } 
            catch (UpdaterException e) 
            {
                    // deal with it                 
            }
        }

    }

// In another class
private UpdateOperation mCurrentUpdateOperation = new UpdateOperation(); 

public void updateRequired()
{
    synchronized (mCurrentUpdateOperation.isInProgress)
    {
        if (!mCurrentUpdateOperation.isInProgress)
        {
            new Thread(mCurrentUpdateOperation).start();
        }
        else
        {
            // reschedule or silently ignore                
        }
    }   
}
```

Is this setup sufficient for no two (2) update operations to run concurrently? I believe it is because the first thread to reach the `synchronized` block will acquire the lock, launch the operation, and release the lock. Then the second (or more) will acquire the lock, see that operation is in progress, reschedule, and release the lock.

Can this setup ever fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this setup sufficient for no two (2) update operations to run concurrently?

No because of the object you are locking on.  You should *always* synchronize on a non-final object and *never* on a `Boolean`.  As the value of `isInProgress` changes (as it is set to `true` or `false`), multiple threads will be locking different objects and can enter the mutex block at the same time.

You could instead lock on your `UpdateOperation` instance if it could be made `final`.  You can always do something like:

```
 private final Object lockObject = new Object();
 ...
 synchronized (lockObject) {
     ...
 }
```

Once you lock the object you can check the state of the `inProgress` which could be a boolean primitive. The `synchronize` construct syncs *all* memory.  See the [Java thread tutorial on synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) for more information.

Locking on a `Boolean` is specifically bad because there are only 2 constant object references for them in the entire JVM (unless you do `new Boolean(...)`).   When you say:

```
isInProgress = true;
```

you are in effect saying:

```
isInProgress = Boolean.TRUE;
```

So all threads in all *classes* will be locking on the same 2 objects with bizarre results.

For more information see my answer here:

> [Why is it not a good practice to synchronize on Boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324272/why-is-it-not-good-practice-to-synchronize-on-boolean/10324280#10324280)

Comment: (+1) Couldn't have said it better.

Comment: With an `Object` lock how do I check the state of the operation?

Comment: You lock the object and then check the state of `inProgress` @SotiriosDelimanolis.  `synchronize` synchronizes _all_ memory so inProgress then can be a primitive boolean if you'd like.  See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: Couldn't I just lock on my `UpdateOperation` object instead of a new one.

Comment: You could if it never changes.  If it was `final` then yes @SotiriosDelimanolis.

Comment: Also, what do I do, when I want to change the value of `isInProgress` inside my `run()`? Do I synchronize on `this`?

Comment: You need to `synchronize` on the _same_ object that the thread synchronizes on.  Take a look a the Java tutorial for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Another problem of the original solution is that checking and setting the `isInProgress` variable is in different synchronized statements, which creates time gap. As a result, more than one thread could be started.

Correct solution is:

```
public class UpdateOperation implements Runnable {
    private boolean inProgress = false;

    public void start() {
       synchronized (this) {
           if (inProgress) {
              return;
           }
           inProgress=true;
       }
       new Thread(this).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try  {
            update(); //perform update
        } catch (UpdaterException e) {
                // deal with it                 
        } finally {
            synchronized (this) {
                inProgress = false;
            }
        }
    }

}

// In another class
private UpdateOperation mCurrentUpdateOperation = new UpdateOperation(); 

public void updateRequired() {
      mCurrentUpdateOperation.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29)s. They will provide a Threadpool and you can simply add you runnable. Also you may want to use AtomicInteger.

I think this will provide you everything you want, is easier to use.

Comment: Using Executors does not help to solve the task. From the task's perspective, there is no difference, if UpdateOperation runs on an executor or on a separate  thread.

Comment: The SingleThreadExecutor will queue you Runnables. So there is only one Operation per time.

Comment: When an update is already running, the OP wants to either "reschedule or silently ignore". With an Executor you reschedule the subsequent operation (it is placed in the queue and executed after), but you cannot get the "silently ignore" behaviour.