# Why does this throw an IllegalMonitorStateException?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am getting into Java multithreading. I am very familiar with C/C++ pthreads, but am having issues with the Java `notify()` and `wait()` functions.

I understand that an `IllegalMoinitorStateException` is only thrown when a thread that doesnt "own" (aka hasnt synchronized) calls notify/wait.

When writing my application, I ran into this issue. I isolated the problem with the following test code:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static Integer notifier = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        notifier = 100;
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                    synchronized (notifier){
                            System.out.println("Notifier is: " + notifier + " waiting");
                            try{
                                notifier.wait();
                                System.out.println("Awake, notifier is " + notifier);
                            }
                            catch (InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                    }
            }});
        thread.start();
        try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        synchronized (notifier){
            notifier = 50;
            System.out.println("Notifier is: " + notifier + " notifying");
            notifier.notify();
        }
        }
    }
```

This outputs:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
        at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
        at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:27)
```

I believe I have already acquired the lock on the notifier object. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT:

From this possible duplicate([Synchronizing on an Integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659915/synchronizing-on-an-integer-value)), it seems that it is not a good idea to synchronize on an Integer because it is hard to make sure you are synchronizing on the same instance. Since my integer I am synchronizing on is a global visibile static integer, why am I getting different instances?

Comment: Possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659915/synchronizing-on-an-integer-value

Comment: Just another hint since it has already been answered: try setting notifier to final. It will not compile since you assign a different value (object) to notifier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of `notifier = 50;` you are calling `notifier.notify();` on a different object.

Answer (score 0):

Initially when you calling synchronized on `notifier` in non-main Thread it was referencing to the object on heap whose content was `0` hence the thread owns that object . Now after non-main thread is put on `wait` using `notifier.wait` the control is given to the main thread . There after acquiring lock on object of Integer containing value 0 you made the `notifier` to refer the other object on heap memory containing value `50` because `notifier = 50;` is actually equivalent to `notifier = new Integer(50)` which means a new object of `Integer` is created and its reference is passed to `notifier`. Now , when the thread sees `notifier.notify` it looks that the Main thread now no longer owns the original object that it had acquired before. So `IllegalMonitorStateException` is throwing.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add more information, you should never synchronize on a non-final object.

You need to synchronize on a constant object. If you synchronized on any object that you are assigning (i.e. changing the object) then the object is not constant and once it assigns the object and tries to notify on it, you will get the `IllegalMonitorStateException`.  It also means that because they are synchronizing on different objects, multiple threads will be entering the protected block at the same time and race conditions will happen.

> Since my integer I am synchronizing on is a global visibile static integer, why am I getting different instances?

When you assign a value to an `Integer` it changes it to a *different* object reference -- even if it is `static`.  You are *not* changing the same object because `Integer` can't be mutated.  So `notifier = 50;` assigns it to a different object than `notifier = 0;`.

If you want to use, for example, a constant object you can use an `AtomicBoolean`:

```
  public static final AtomicInteger notifier = new AtomicInteger(0);
  ...
  synchronize (notifier) {
      notifier.set(50);
      ...
  }
```

Here, `AtomicInteger` can be marked `final` because it's the same object all of the time.

For more information, see: [Why is it not a good practice to synchronize on Boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324272/why-is-it-not-good-practice-to-synchronize-on-boolean/10324280#10324280)