# Bank Simulator with Synchronization in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-synchronization

I have a method transfer() which withdrawals money from one account and deposits it into another. There are 10 accounts each running with their own thread. I have another method test() which sums up the total in each account to make sure that the bank has not lost or gained money. In order to have an accurate total, I created a boolean flag to indicate if testing is in progress. If it is, I need to somehow suspend the transfers until the test is finished. I've tried to implement this using a synchronized block to tell the threads to wait on a condition and release once the condition is no longer true. For some reason I'm having difficulty. My transfer method looks like this:

```
public class Bank {

    public static final int NTEST = 10;
    private Account[] accounts;
    private long ntransacts = 0;
    private int initialBalance;
    private int numAccounts;
    private boolean open;
    private int transactsInProgress;
    private boolean testing=false;

    public Bank(int numAccounts, int initialBalance) {
        open = true;
        this.initialBalance = initialBalance;
        this.numAccounts = numAccounts;
        accounts = new Account[numAccounts];
        for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
            accounts[i] = new Account(this, i, initialBalance);
        }
        ntransacts = 0;
        transactsInProgress = 0;
    }
    public synchronized void incrementTransacts(){
        transactsInProgress++;
    }
    public synchronized void decrementTransacts(){
        transactsInProgress--;
    }

    public void transfer(int from, int to, int amount) throws InterruptedException {

    accounts[from].waitForAvailableFunds(amount);
    synchronized(this){
        while(testing){
            System.out.println("Cannot transfer while testing...");
            this.wait();
        }
    }
        if (!open) return;
        if (accounts[from].withdraw(amount)) {
            incrementTransacts(); //synchronzied method increments transactsInProgress
            accounts[to].deposit(amount);
            decrementTransacts(); //synchronized method
        }
        if (shouldTest()) test();

    synchronized(this){
        this.notifyAll();
    }    
    }

    public synchronized void test() throws InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;

        testing=true;
        while(transactsInProgress!=0){
                System.out.println("Cannot test while transactions are in progres... \nWaiting...");
            wait();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%s %s%n", 
                    Thread.currentThread().toString(),accounts[i].toString());
            sum += accounts[i].getBalance();
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().toString() + 
                " Sum: " + sum);
        if (sum != numAccounts * initialBalance) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().toString() + 
                    " Money was gained or lost");
            System.exit(1);
        } else {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().toString() + 
                    " The bank is in balance");
        }
        testing=false;
        notifyAll();
    }
       public int size() {
        return accounts.length;
    }

    public synchronized boolean isOpen() {return open;}

    public void closeBank() {
        synchronized (this) {
            open = false;
        }
        for (Account account : accounts) {
            synchronized(account) {
                account.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized boolean shouldTest() {
        return ++ntransacts % NTEST == 0;
    }
}
```

It's been a while since I've coded in Java and I'm new to threads and concurrency so I'm not sure exactly where I'm going wrong. When I run the program, the bank sum is incorrect. Theres 10,000 in each account so the sum each time should be 100,000. Any ideas here?

EDIT: The thread class and Main:

```
class TransferThread extends Thread {

    public TransferThread(Bank b, int from, int max) {
        bank = b;
        fromAccount = from;
        maxAmount = max;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            int toAccount = (int) (bank.size() * Math.random());
            int amount = (int) (maxAmount * Math.random());
            bank.transfer(fromAccount, toAccount, amount);
        }
        bank.closeBank();
    }
    private Bank bank;
    private int fromAccount;
    private int maxAmount;
}
```

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Bank b = new Bank(NACCOUNTS, INITIAL_BALANCE);
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[NACCOUNTS];
    // Start a thread for each account
    for (int i = 0; i < NACCOUNTS; i++) {
        threads[i] = new TransferThread(b, i, INITIAL_BALANCE);
        threads[i].start();
    }
    // Wait for all threads to finish
    for (int i = 0; i < NACCOUNTS; i++) {
        try {
            threads[i].join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // Ignore this
        }
    }
    b.test();
}
```

Comment: Can you please post code for thread class? I am assuming that the transaction is done by thread (not main thread).

Comment: I added the thread class and my main method.

Comment: When you are testing all the threads should wait. How are you passing that message to other threads?

Comment: Also upload the code for Bank class.

Comment: In the transfer method, while testing is set to true, it tells the thread to wait until it's notified that the testing is done.

Comment: The boolean variable value is not known to other threads and they will not wait for it.

Comment: Why would you have a thread per account?  Threads _do_ things, accounts don't.  I like to define threads in terms of what they wait for (e.g., a thread that waits for the next command, or a pool thread that waits for a task to perform).  Of course, the thread then has to _do_ something when it receives the event that it awaited (e.g., execute the command, perform the task.)  I can't imagine what an account thread would wait for.  `Account` sounds like an object upon which threads operate, not a thread itself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your exact issue, but there are a few concerning things in your code:

1. Your `transfer()` method has two different `synchronized` blocks, but appears to perform operations which should be protected between them.
2. Don't trust primitive `boolean` variables for synchronization. When you're working with multiple threads you should use [AtomicBoolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html).

**Update now that I understand the problem a little better:**

The issue here is that you're using trying to use `synchronized` in a manner which wasn't intended by its designers. If you're going to synchronize, you pick an object and say "only one thread can manipulate this thing at a time". Using `synchronized(this)` or declaring methods as `synchronized` in your `Bank` class says "only one thread can manipulate the state of the bank at once".

From your comment below, I understand that's not the case. If multiple threads can update accounts at once, the bank isn't the resource you want to synchronize on.

You should either protect at a more granular level (e.g., locking each account individually), or use a different lock construct such as [ReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) which allows multiple threads to say share a lower level of access or a single thread to gain exclusive access.

Comment: "Don't trust primitive boolean variables for synchronization." Well we can if they are volatile.

Comment: There are some subtle differences. Consider two threads simultaneously negating the value of the boolean. Even if we know they're reading from the same spot in memory (per volatile), there is no guarantee that after I've read "False" that another thread hasn't set it to "True" before I do my write.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786825/volatile-boolean-vs-atomicboolean

Comment: The transfer method should be able to allow multiple accounts to transfer money at the same time so I can't make the whole method synchronized.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your objective. I think you want a [ReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html).

Your test method will acquire a `write lock`, which will block all transfers. Your transfer threads will acquire a `read lock` which will allow them all to execute concurrently, but will block the test method.

Comment: Is there a way that I can still have it so that the flag in the test method causes the transfer threads to be suspended? But otherwise the ReadWriteLock seems to be what I needed!

Comment: You should _never_ sync on a boolean.  Not even if it is volatile @akhil_mittal.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10324280/179850

Comment: But that said, the code never does synchronize on a boolean.  It has method level synchronization which is syncing on the `this` which return `boolean` but that's different.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is not immediately apparent however this looks wrong:

```
    if (accounts[from].withdraw(amount)) {
        incrementTransacts(); //synchronzied method increments transactsInProgress
        accounts[to].deposit(amount);
        decrementTransacts(); //synchronized method
    }
```

This section of code is not synchronized.  If 2 threads are trying to deposit to the same account, they might overwrite each other.  Or if there aren't any memory barriers, the correct balance may not be published correctly.  You aren't showing the `Account` object but if it is not thread-safe, that's probably the source of the issue.

Each account could have an `AtomicInteger` balance that would then be updated atomically and in a thread-safe manner.

```
class Account {
   private final AtomicInteger balance = new AtomicInteger(0);
   ...
   public int withdraw(int amount) {
        // loop to get the money in a thread-safe manner
        while (true) {
           // get current balance
           int current = balance.get();
           if (current < amount) {
               // not enough funds
               return 0;
           }
           // update the balance atomically if it is still current
           if (balance.compareAndSet(current, current - amount)) {
               return amount;
           }
           // someone else beat me to it so loop and get new balance
       }
   }

   public void deposit(int amount) {
       // similar but without the not-enough-funds check and with a +
   }
```

Here are some other issues in your code that might help.

1. > accounts[from].waitForAvailableFunds(amount);

   You are waiting for funds and then withdrawing them.  There is a race condition there that might cause another 2 threads to both return true but only one thread would actually get the funds.  We also can't see the `Account` class to make sure that it is thread-safe.

   I would have some sort of `accounts[from].waitAndWithdraw(...)` method which would wait until the account has funds and then withdraw it.
2. It seems to me that you could deadlock your system pretty easily if you get the right combination of withdraw and deposit commands.  For example, if 10 withdraws were happening, none of them might have the funds and your system would just stop.  You could do a `wait(...)` with a timeout and return an error code (or throw) if the timeout is reached.

   This won't happen from your `main(...)` as written but other users could do it.
3. `public synchronized void decrementTransacts(){ transactsInProgress--; }`

   This sort of code is begging for use of `AtomicInteger`.  Then you can do `transactsInProgress.incrementAndGet()` without the sync lock.
4. As @Tyler mentions, you might consider synchronizing instead on the `Account` objects instead of the `Bank`.  So the `Bank` would just be the class that issues the transfer but the locks would be localized on the `Account` objects to make sure they are thread-safe.  Or with the above code, many of the sync locks may not be necessary.
5. It is pretty obvious that there are times that the `test()` is going to fail since there are times when you have withdrawn an amount from one account but may not have deposited the same amount in the other account.