# Why the result which the system should print to me changes every time(java concurrency)?

Tags: java, multithreading, variables, concurrency

I have a problem in concurrency programming in java. Please look at the code below. The result which system should print to  me, changes every time I run the program.  Although I’ve synchronized the operation of adding value to sub variable, but the result changes every time. I think I’ve made a mistake somewhere. But I do not know where.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final MyClass mClass = new MyClass();
        int size = 10;
        final CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(size);
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for(int number = 0; number < 100000; number++){
                        mClass.addToSub(number);
                    }
                    cdl.countDown();
                }
            });
            t.start();
        }
        try {
            cdl.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //the result changes every time!!!!!!!!
        System.out.println(mClass.getSub());
    }

    public static class MyClass {
        private Long sub = 0L;
        public long getSub() {
            synchronized (sub) {
                return sub;
            }
        }
        public void addToSub(long value){
            synchronized (sub) {
                sub += value;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: A similar one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324272/why-is-it-not-a-good-practice-to-synchronize-on-boolean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are getting wrong here is not the multi-threading. What is causing this issue is a java feature called auto-boxing.

Your variable `sub` has the type `Long` which is a reference to an object (`Long` and `long` are different).

You need to have an object to synchronize on in java so you can not use just a normal `long`.

The problem here is that a `Long` is immutable meaning the value does not change. So when you do `sub += value` you are actually doing `sub = Long.valueOf(sub.longValue() + value)` witch is creating a new object.

So the current thread only has the previous object locked so new threads can still change the reference `sub`.

What you want to do is synchronize on a reference that wont change, i.e `this`

```
public void addToSub(long value){
    synchronized (this) {
        sub += value;
    }
}
```

Or more terse:

```
public synchronized void addToSub(long value) {
    sub += value;
}
```

And you should probably use `long` and not `Long`.

**EDIT**

As noted in [Thomas Timbul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49755121/9316430)s answer you probably want to use [AtomicLong](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) as that gives you thread-safety by default and potentially much better performance (as the threads don't need to wait for each-other).

Answer (score 2):

In `addToSub` you are changing the value on which you `synchronize`. Effectively this means that there is no synchronization at all.

Either sync on `this`, or even better, use [AtomicLong](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) and avoid both your problem as well as synchronization overhead (Thread contention):

```
public static class MyClass {
    private AtomicLong sub = new AtomicLong();
    public long getSub() {
        return sub.get();
    }
    public void addToSub(long value){
        sub.addAndGet(value);
    }
}
```

The Atomic* classes are specifically designed for this type of usecase, where a single variable is updated by multiple Threads, and where `synchronize` could result in heavy thread contention. If you are dealing with Collections, look towards the ones in `java.util.concurrent.*`

Edit:
Thanks for the correction of `addAndGet` vs `incrementAndGet`.

Comment: `incrementAndGet` -> `addAndGet`?

Answer (score 1):

You're synchronizing on a non-final value:

```
synchronized (sub) {
```

This means that as soon as you change it to some other value:

```
sub += value;
```

anything which isn't already waiting at the synchronized block can proceed, because nothing is holding the monitor for this new value.

Synchronize on `this` instead (or some other unchanging value):

```
synchronized (this) {
```

Answer (score 1):

sub is an object (Long), change to long and add a private Object for the synchronized. Then it will work.

```
public static class MyClass {
        private Object locker = new Object();
        private long sub = 0L;
        public long getSub() {
            synchronized (locker) {
                return sub;
            }
        }
        public void addToSub(long value){
            synchronized (locker) {
                sub += value;
            }
        }
}
```