# Does Java monitor include instance variables?

Tags: java, synchronized

Is it that monitor in Java does not restrict access to instance variables and only to the methods which are declared *synchronized* or code in *synchronized* statements?

I have created two threads, `thread y` invokes `sync()` method, which is declared *synchronized* while `thread r` invokes `unsync()` method which is not declared synchronized. Both invoke methods on shared object `s`.

`Thread r` is able to modify the instance variable of object `s` while the *monitor* or *lock* of that object is still being held by the `thread y`.

Is it that the monitor in Java does not restrict access to instance variables, and only to the methods which are declared *synchronized* or code in *synchronized* statements?

```
public class Stuff {

    private int a = 10;

    public synchronized void sync() {
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Okay, I am in sync() method. "
                        + "I will be waiting for 10 seconds. Current Time = "
                        + System.currentTimeMillis());
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() - t1 < 10000);
        System.out.println("Okay, I have waited for 10 seconds. Current time is "
                        + System.currentTimeMillis()
                        + ". Now I will exit from sync() method, a = " + this.a);
    }

    public void unsync() {
        System.out.println("Alright, I am in unsync() method. The current time is "
                        + System.currentTimeMillis());
        this.a = this.a + 1;
        System.out.println(". The time of exit from unsync() method is "
                        + System.currentTimeMillis());

    }
}

class T1 extends Thread {

    Stuff s;

    public T1(Stuff s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public void run() {
        s.sync();
    }
}

class T2 extends Thread {

    Stuff s;

    public T2(Stuff s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public void run() {
        s.unsync();
    }
}

class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Stuff s = new Stuff();
        T1 y = new T1(s);
        T2 r = new T2(s);
        y.start();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        r.start();
    }
}
```

The output of the program is below:

> ```
>  
> Okay, I am in sync() method. I will be waiting for 10 seconds. Current Time = 1358801766310  
> Alright, I am in unsync() method. The current time is 1358801768343. The time of exit from unsync() method is 1358801768343  
> Okay, I have waited for 10 seconds. Current time is 1358801776310. Now I will exit from sync() method, a = 11
> ```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes. Holding the monitor of an object prevents another thread from executing another block of code or synchronized on the same object. If a method is not synchronized, any thread can call it at any time, whether another thread holds a monitor or not.

Every access to a shared stated, even read-only accessed, must be synchronized if there's a chance that at least one thread modifies this shared state.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it that monitor in java does not restrict access to instance variables and only to the methods which are declared synchronized or code in synchronized statements?

Yes.

Synchronized blocks (or methods) are, among other things, mutually exclusive. That does not prevent the object used as a lock (the monitor, let's call it `lock`) to be used outside those blocks, in which case no synchronization will be performed. For example, one thread could read or write `lock` while another thread is within a synchronized block where `lock` is the monitor.

If you want to restrict access to a variable, you need to make sure that all accesses are made while holding a lock (any lock, provided it is the same for each access).

Answer (score 3):

Making methods synchronized has two effects:

First, it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave. When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object.

Second, when a synchronized method exits, it automatically establishes a happens-before relationship with any subsequent invocation of a synchronized method for the same object. This guarantees that changes to the state of the object are visible to all threads.

(source: [the Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html))