# Synchronization of methods, objects, class in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-synchronization

I need some clarification with regards to use of `synchronization` in `multi-threaded environment`. I have a small example `Class` below. but I am actually finding it hard to make a test case of how the following will work; The reason I want test case is to the understand how `synchronization` handles these different scenarios

---

- If a `thread` calls `SharedResource.staticMethod`, it will acquire the `lock` for the `class.` does it mean an `instance` of `SharedResource`, say x, will have to wait till it gets `lock` to exectute `x.staticMethod`.
- Will `synchronization` of `this` in a `block`, acquires the lock for that section of the code or for entire `object`. i.e can another `thread` call the same `method` on same `object`; but execute the remainder of the code that is not part of `synchronization block`
- If the above point is true, having a `dummy object` to `lock` on does not provide any additional benefit. Correct?
- So there are different levels of `synchronziations`. `Class` level, `Object` level, `method` level and `block level`. so that would mean `locks` for these individual levels should exist?
  If I acquired a lock on the `Object`, another `Thread` cannot call any `methods` on the `same object`, but if I acquired a lock on the `method`, another `thread` can acquire lock on a different `method`. Is this correct?

Some tips on on how to create two threads that act on same object and same method will be helpful (I understand I need to extend `Thread` class or implement `Runnable` interface). But not sure how to make a two threads call the same method on same object.

```
class SharedResource {
     public Integer x =0;
     public static Integer y=0;
     Object dummy = new Object();
     public Integer z=0;

     public synchronized static void staticMethod(){
         System.out.println("static Method is called");
         y++; 
     }

     public synchronized void incrementX(){
         System.out.println("instance method; incrementX");
         x++;
     }

     public void incrementXBlock(){
         synchronized(this){
             x++;
         }
         System.out.println("instance method; incrementXBlock");
     }

     public void incrementZ(){
         synchronized (dummy) {
             z++;
         } 
         System.out.println("synchronized on dummy; incrementZ method ");
     }
}

public class ThreadSynchronization extends Thread {

}
```

I have read these posts, but I am not positive if I understood it clearly.

[Java synchronized method lock on object, or method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047564/java-synchronized-method-lock-on-object-or-method), [Does java monitor include instance variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447095/does-java-monitor-include-instance-variables)

Comment: There is also good article about java synchronization http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/synchronization-in-java-synchronized.html

Comment: There is only one type of synchronization and that's on an object. Where and how the synchronized is used determines which object that is.

Comment: Java runs in the way of monitors. So when you synchronize object objectA, and objectB there is different lock acquired.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html mentions that "When a thread invokes a synchronized method, it automatically acquires the intrinsic lock for that method's object and releases it when the method returns." does that mean a lock for method exists?

Comment: @eagertoLearn It says `that method's object`. An instance method is invoked on an object. The thread will acquire that object's monitor. There is no such thing as a method lock.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: so that would prevent another thread from executing other methods of the same object..correct? that would be inefficient correct?

Comment: No, nothing **ever** prevents another thread from executing a method. If that other thread tries to execute a block of code synchronized on the same object, then it will wait until that other thread has released the monitor.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I see, although Thread1 has acquired the  lock for the object, it basically locks up the syncronized blocks in the that object, so other part is free for other threads to access?

Comment: There is just synchronizing on the class, and synchronizing on the object, and when a synchronized method is called it waits until it gets an exclusive lock on the object before proceeding. There are not different locks for different methods of an object, or for sections of code within a method. They just lock the object they are part of.

Comment: I want to say yes, but I'm worried you are making other assumptions. [Read this tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class SharedResource {
  public synchronized static void staticMethod(){
    System.out.println("static Method is called");
    y++; 
  }
  public synchronized void incrementX(){
     System.out.println("instance method; incrementX");
     x++;
  }
}
```

does the same as

```
class SharedResource {
  public static void staticMethod(){
    synchronized(SharedResource.class) {
      System.out.println("static Method is called");
      y++;
    }
  }
  public void incrementX(){
    synchronized(this) {
      System.out.println("instance method; incrementX");
      x++;
    }
  }
}
```

Simply said, a thread entering a synchronized block will acquire a lock on the specified object for the duration of the block. This implies that at most one thread can execute a `synchronized` code block for a particular lock object. Since the `Class` instance and a particular instance of that class are different object, `synchronized static` methods and `synchronized` instance methods do not block each other. But there is no difference between “method level” and “block level”; the important point is which object is chosen for the synchronization.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I would like to test some of these, how can I create a two threads that act on same objects and call same methods? the last point of in my question

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html Section “Defining and Starting a Thread” or “The SimpleThreads Example”