# Producer Consumer in java multithreaded

Tags: java, multithreading, consumer, producer

I'm trying to implement a Producer Consumer problem in java. I'm using a circular buffer (circular array) to for the Producer to insert items into the buffer. Following is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Buffer
{
    String a[];
    int front, rear;

    public Buffer(int size)
    {
            a = new String[size];
            front = rear = -1;
    }

    public boolean insert(String dataitem)
    {
            int p;
            p = (rear+1) % a.length;

            if(p==front)
            {
                    System.out.println("Buffer full");
                    return false;
            }
            else
            {       rear = p;
                    a[rear] = dataitem;
                    if(front == -1)
                            front = 0;
                    return true;
            }
    }

    public boolean empty()
    {
            if(front == -1)
                    return true;
            else
                    return false;
    }

    public String delete()
    {
            String result = a[front];
            if(front == rear)
                    front = rear = -1;
            else
                    front = (front +1)%a.length;
            return result;
    }

    public void display()
    {
            if(front == -1)
                    System.out.println("Buffer empty");
else
            {
                    System.out.println("Buffer elements are:");
                    int i= front;

                    while(i!= rear)
                    {
                            System.out.println(a[i]);
                            i = (i+1)%a.length;
                    }
                    System.out.println(a[i]);
            }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            int size = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

            Buffer b = new Buffer(size);
            int ch;
            String dataitem, msg;

            Thread prod = new Thread(new Producer(b, size));
            Thread cons = new Thread(new Consumer(b, size));

            prod.start();
            cons.start();
    }

}

class Producer extends Thread
{
    Buffer b;
    int size;

    public Producer(Buffer b, int size)
    {
            this.b = b;
            this.size = size;
    }

    public void run()
    {
            while(true)
            {
                    synchronized(b)
                    {
                    for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
                    {
                            try
                            {       String dataitem = Thread.currentThread().getId()+"_"+i;
                                    boolean bool = b.insert(dataitem);
                                    //b.notifyAll();
if(bool)
                                            System.out.println("Successfully inserted "+dataitem);
                                    b.notifyAll();
                                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                            }
                            catch(Exception e)
                            {       e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }

            }
            }
    }
}

class Consumer extends Thread
{
    Buffer b;
    int size;

    public Consumer(Buffer b, int size)
    {
            this.b = b;
            this.size = size;
    }

    public void run()
    {
            while(b.empty())
            {
                    synchronized(b)
                    {
                            try
                            {
                                    System.out.println("Buffer empty");
                                    b.wait();
                            }
                            catch(Exception e)
                            {       e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }
            }

            synchronized(b)
            {
                    b.notifyAll();
                    String dataitem = b.delete();
                    System.out.println("Removed "+dataitem);
            }

    }
}
```

The producer is inserting dataitems into the buffer successfully. But they aren't being consumed by the consumer.

I get the following output when I execute the program.

```
Successfully inserted 11_1
Successfully inserted 11_2
Buffer full
Buffer full
Buffer full
Buffer full
Buffer full
Buffer full
```

My question is how do I get the consumer to consume items from the buffer?

Comment: Your `synchronized(b)` in the `Producer` will never unlock, which is preventing the `Consumer` from consuming anything...

Comment: How do I resolve that?

Answer (score 1):

The major problem is that the `synchronized` block in your `Producer` is too wide.  It is never letting the `Consumer` acquire the lock

Start by narrowing the scope, for example...

```
while (true) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        try {
            String dataitem = Thread.currentThread().getId() + "_" + i;
            boolean bool = b.insert(dataitem);
            //b.notifyAll();
            if (bool) {
                System.out.println("Successfully inserted " + dataitem);
            }
            synchronized (b) {
                b.notifyAll();
            }
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You may also consider synchronizing the ing `insert` and `delete` methods themselves.  I personally would be tempted to use a internal lock, but you could simply `synchronize` the methods themselves, for example...

```
public synchronized boolean insert(String dataitem) {...}

public synchronized String delete() {...}
```

As it stands, your `Consumer` will only ever read a single value from the buffer, but I'll let you figure that one out ;)

As a side note, I might put the wait and notify functionality directly within the `Buffer`, so that whenever you try and `delete` a value, it will wait, within the `delete` method for the `Buffer` to be not empty and allow the `insert` method to make the notifications itself...but that's me ;)

Equally, I might consider blocking the `insert` method until there is more room, but that will come down to how you want to implement it :P

**Updated**

Very basically, this will start giving the results you are looking for...

```
public class ProducerConsumer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ProducerConsumer();
    }

    public ProducerConsumer() {
        int size = 5;

        Buffer b = new Buffer(size);

        Thread prod = new Thread(new Producer(b, size));
        Thread cons = new Thread(new Consumer(b, size));

        prod.start();
        cons.start();
    }

    public class Buffer {

        String a[];
        int front, rear;

        public Buffer(int size) {
            a = new String[size];
            front = rear = -1;
        }

        public synchronized boolean insert(String dataitem) {
            int p;
            p = (rear + 1) % a.length;

            if (p == front) {
                System.out.println("Buffer full");
                return false;
            } else {
                rear = p;
                a[rear] = dataitem;
                if (front == -1) {
                    front = 0;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

        public boolean empty() {
            return front == -1;
        }

        public synchronized String delete() {
            String result = a[front];
            if (front == rear) {
                front = rear = -1;
            } else {
                front = (front + 1) % a.length;
            }
            return result;
        }

        public void display() {
            if (front == -1) {
                System.out.println("Buffer empty");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Buffer elements are:");
                int i = front;

                while (i != rear) {
                    System.out.println(a[i]);
                    i = (i + 1) % a.length;
                }
                System.out.println(a[i]);
            }
        }

    }

    class Producer extends Thread {

        Buffer b;
        int size;

        public Producer(Buffer b, int size) {
            this.b = b;
            this.size = size;
        }

        public void run() {
            int i = 0;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    String dataitem = Thread.currentThread().getId() + "_" + ++i;
                    boolean bool = b.insert(dataitem);
                    if (bool) {
                        System.out.println("Successfully inserted " + dataitem);
                    }
                    synchronized (b) {
                        b.notifyAll();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    class Consumer extends Thread {

        Buffer b;
        int size;

        public Consumer(Buffer b, int size) {
            this.b = b;
            this.size = size;
        }

        public void run() {

            while (true) {

                while (b.empty()) {
                    synchronized (b) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Buffer empty");
                            b.wait();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                String dataitem = null;
                synchronized (b) {
                    dataitem = b.delete();
                }
                    System.out.println("Removed " + dataitem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After synchronizing the methods and that block in the Producer class, it works fine. But when I enter the Buffer size as 2, I get the following output: " Successfully inserted 11_1
Removed 11_1
Successfully inserted 11_2
Successfully inserted 11_1
Buffer full
Buffer full "

Comment: The `Producer` has two loops, a `while(true)` and `for-loop`.  The `while` loop is forcing the `for-loop` to repeat indefinitely.  You may consider removing the outer `while-loop` which will stop the thread after it has completed adding the required number of elements

Comment: But I'm supposed to continuously add elements into the buffer and simultaneously read from the buffer.

Comment: If I remove the `while(true)`, i get the following output: ` Buffer empty
Successfully inserted 11_1
Removed 11_1
Successfully inserted 11_2 `

Comment: Then start by `dropping` the `for-loop`, the `while-loop` will take care of it (in the `Produce`) and add a `while(true) {...}` around the contents of the `Consumer`

Comment: But I have to increment each data item. It should be like 11_1, 11_2, 11_3 and so on in the buffer. That's why I used the `for-loop` in the `Producer`.

Comment: So, keep a counter in the `while` loop and increment on each loop.  The `size`, as I understand, is the size of the `Buffer`, not the loops...

Comment: Yup, the `size` is the size of the `Buffer`. What do you mean by keeping a counter in the `while` loop and incrementing it on each loop?

Comment: `int counter = 0; while(true) { count++;...}`

Comment: I still keep getting the `Buffer full` as output. The consumer is not consuming the data items. :(

Comment: I took the `Thread.sleep` out of the `Producer`, you could put one back in after the `b.notifyAll` (outside of the synchronized block) which should give the consumer time to run).  You could also use `Thread.yield();`, but `Thread.sleep` might give you better results

Comment: call the b.insert also inside the synchronized(b) block. The update to the front variables should be synchronized between the insert and delete calls.

Comment: @Raji That's why the method is `synchronized`, but that may give better results...I'd prefer it if the `Buffer` was more thread safe :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047564/java-synchronized-method-lock-on-object-or-method ... "Summary : Locking is only at synchronized method level and object's instance variables can be accessed by other thread"

Comment: @Raji As I understand it the method synchronisation is locking on the object instance, so that with `remove` and `insert` being `synchronised`, when one thread is in `remove`, no other thread can gain access to `remove` or `insert` - yes, there are other methods that aren't in this example, but this is simple start...