# synchronized method use as a mutex in java

Tags: java, mutex

i coundn't understand an simple question,

what does a synchronized method use as a `mutex` in java-

a) A globally declared mutex
b) A method's mutex
c) A owning object's(this's) mutex

can anybody elaborate this?
thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java synchronized method lock on object, or method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047564/java-synchronized-method-lock-on-object-or-method)

Comment: no i am taking about mutex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s option c); from [Goetz et al. (2006), *Java Concurrency in Practice*](http://jcip.net/):

> A `synchronized` method is a shorthand for a `synchronized` block that spans an entire method body, and whose lock is the object on which the method is being invoked. (Static `synchronized` methods use the `Class` object for the lock.)