# Synchronized block will lock the whole object or the method alone?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, synchronized

I have multiple methods in a class and most of the methods are having critical sections(shared data). So I made those methods as synchronized. Say thread t1 is running one of the synchronized block . At the same time thread t2 can access the other methods critical section ?

```
class Sample{

synchronized public void method1(){

}

synchronized public void method2(){

}

synchronized public void method3(){

}

public void method4(){

}

}
```

Comment: the whole object

Comment: @JavaUser 

Assumption : All the thread are created with same Sample Object
Answer: If any of the synchronized method (method1 or method2 or method3) is called then all the other Synchronized method will remain blocked till execution is completed . Method 4 will never get block , whatever the situation could be.

Comment: Conversely, if you have two objects of the same type, `Sample s1 = new Sample(); Sample s2 = new Sample();` then when a synchronized method is called on `s1`, only `s1` is locked and not `s2`.  That should be obvious but sometimes people forget there's a difference.

Comment: A synchronized instance method in Java is synchronized on the instance (object) owning the method. Thus, each instance has its synchronized methods synchronized on a different object: the owning instance. Only one thread can execute inside a synchronized instance method. If more than one instance exist, then one thread at a time can execute inside a synchronized instance method per instance. One thread per instance. see http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html#synchronized-instance-methods

Comment: And if `synchronized` method is `static`, then the method owner and that block's monitor is the `Class`, so whole class gets locked.

Comment: Also, if you want the full skinny on Java multithreading, read chapter 17 of the specification.  But also get the book ["Java Concurrency in Practice"](http://jcip.net/) by Brian Goetz.  It's *the* book for Java multithreading.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047564/java-synchronized-method-lock-on-object-or-method?rq=1, possible dup

Answer (score 12):

synchronized is always locking on an object. In case of a synchronized method, the object is `this`. So basically these two methods do the same:

```
synchronized public void method1() {
  // do something
}
```

and

```
public void method1() {
  synchronized(this){
    // do something
  }
}
```

As long as one thread has the lock on the lock object, no other thread can lock this object. So in your example, the synchronized methods (one, two and three) can never be executed at the same time. `method4` is not synchronized, so it can access the object anytime.

If you want a more fine-grained locking, because `method1`and `method2` should be exclusive and `method3`and `method4` you could use for example something like this:

```
class Sample{
  private final Object lock1 = new Object();
  private final Object lock2 = new Object();

  public void method1(){
    synchronized(lock1) {
      // do something
    }
  }
  public void method2(){
    synchronized(lock1) {
      // do something
    }
  }

  public void method3(){
    synchronized(lock2) {
      // do something
    }
  }
  public void method4(){
    synchronized(lock2) {
      // do something
    }
  }
}
```

You can then even use the `synchonized(lock)` method to just wrap the statements that need to be synchronized, not the whole method:

```
public void method() {
  // some code
  synchronized(lock) {
    // code that must be synchronized
  }
  // some other code
}
```

With this approach you can keep the lock duration to a minimum.

Comment: This is correct, but it should be noted, that in general synchronized should be avoided. It is a brutish method to archive thread-safety and in most cases Concurrent classes are much more suited for the task.

Comment: @TwoThe: I totally agree, I prefer immutable objects, event based and / or stream based architectures etc., but that is a different story.

Comment: It should probably be also noted that `synchronized static` methods lock on the `Class` object of the class.

Comment: @TwoThe, In what way is `synchronized` brutish?  It's simple, it's safe, and it's effective.  `java.util.concurrent.locks` provides alternatives that are more powerful, but more power means less safety.  If you are talking about other classes in `java.util.concurrent` (e.g., thread-safe queues, maps, etc.) then of course it would be foolish to re-invent those when one of them solves a problem, but they do not solve every problem.

Comment: synchronized is also exclusive, which means that it puts all threads on hold to serve only a single one. In many situations that greatly reduces the throughput of applications, in worst cases it turns them back to single-threaded. Those downsides can usually be completely avoided when properly using Concurrent classes.

Answer (score 0):

- It is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave. When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object.
- When a synchronized method exits, it automatically establishes a happens-before relationship with any subsequent invocation of a synchronized method for the same object. This guarantees that changes to the state of the object are visible to all threads

Answer (score 0):

In the case

```
Sample sample1 = new Sample();
```

Multiple threads can't access

```
sample1.method1(),sample1.method2(),sample1.method3()
```

But Multiple threads can access concurrently

```
sample1.method4()
```

if we have 2 objects

```
Sample sample1 = new Sample();
Sample sample2 = new Sample();
```

Multiple threads can access cocurrently

```
sample1.method1(),sample2.method1() etc.
```

so the lock is at object level