# How to make notify() execute before wait(), i tried using sleep() but still not working

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, wait, java-threads

I have the following Thread example:

```
class Q
{
    int num;
    public synchronized void put(int num) {
        System.out.println("Put :"+num);
        this.num = num;
        try {Thread.sleep(100);} catch (Exception e) {}
        notify();
        try {wait();} catch (Exception e) {}
    }
    public synchronized void get() {
        try {wait();} catch (Exception e) {}
        System.out.println("Get :"+num);
        notify();
    }
}
class Producer implements Runnable
{
    Q q;
    public Producer(Q q) {
        this.q = q;
        Thread t = new Thread(this,"Producer");
        t.start();
    }
     public void run() {
         int i = 0;
         while(true) {
             q.put(i++);
                try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (Exception e) {}
         }  
     }
}
class Consumer implements Runnable
{
    Q q;
    Thread t;
    public Consumer(Q q) {
        this.q = q;
        t = new Thread(this,"Consumer");
        t.start();
    }
     public void run() {
         while(true) {
             q.get();
            try {Thread.sleep(500);} catch (Exception e) {}
         }     
     }
}
public class InterThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Q q = new Q();
        new Producer(q);
        new Consumer(q);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to run two threads, consumer and producer, in a loop. 
sharing the same object q, one thread incrementing q.num and printing the value of it, and the other is consuming q.num by just printing its value.
The result I'm getting in a console is "Put :0" and stops there,
consumer thread not being called, even though I used `Thread.sleep(100);`
before calling notify() in the producer thread, why !!?

Comment: You should pay attention to [the documentation of `wait`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--), especially the part: “*this method should always be used in a loop `while (<condition does not hold>) wait();`*” Your code does not only fail to check the condition, there is not even a condition to check, as the producer is not producing anything and the consumer does not consume. All you have created, is some kind of counter.

Comment: yes, i know it's not the proper way to use `wait()` i just want to understand what this code is doing exactly.

Comment: Never, ever call `sleep()` from within a _critical section_ (i.e., from inside a `synchronized` block or a `synchronized` method or, while keeping a `Lock` object locked.)  The only exception would be if you were writing an example to demonstrate why it is a \*Bad Idea\* for a critical section to do anything that takes a long time.

Comment: Why are you waiting inside `put()` at all? Ask yourself. What exactly are you waiting *for,* and what are you going to do when it's over? A: nothing and nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, Producer thread is starting before Consumer. notify() is getting called, following by that wait() getting called. Producer thread goes in waiting state, releases acquired lock.

```
// producer
notify();
try {
   System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Put :"+num);
   this.wait(); // lock released
} 
catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Now consumer thread acquires the lock, wait() is executed. `Consumer` goes in the waiting state.

```
// consumer
try {
   System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "Get :"+num);
   this.wait(); // Both the threads are waiting
} 
catch (Exception e) { 

}
```

Now both the threads are waiting for `notify` call from the other thread
Note that `Sleep()` method doesn't release the lock , so there is no point in calling calling `Thread.sleep` before the producer's notify

[difference-between-wait-and-sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1036754/3734640)

Comment: why `try {Thread.sleep(100);} catch (Exception e) {} ` in producer can't make consumer thread goes in waiting state before `notify()` being called in producer.

Comment: You're both the methods are `synchronized`, synchronized method needs lock on`this`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047564/java-synchronized-method-lock-on-object-or-method

Comment: "Classic deadlock," would be when each of the other threads is waiting for the other to _release a resource_ that each of them needs.  The OP's problem is different. Some authors call it "lost notification." The author expects that the one thread will wake the other by calling `notify()`, but the notification was delivered at a time when the second thread was not yet `wait()`ing for it, and so it's as if the notification never happened,.