# What is an ad-hoc lock?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

What is an ad-hoc lock

```
synchronized (obj){
 critical section 
}
```

I understand this acquires the intrinsic lock for `obj`.

```
public void transfer(int from, int to, int amount){
      synchronized (lock){ // an ad-hoc lock
         accounts[from] -= amount;
         accounts[to] += amount;
      }
      System.out.println(. . .);
}
```

What does the `synchronized (lock)` means in the above code.

What is an `ad-hoc` lock?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "ad-hoc lock" in java.

Comment: Have a look at it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047564/java-synchronized-method-lock-on-object-or-method

Answer (score 1):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc):

> *Ad hoc* is a Latin phrase meaning literally 'for this'. In English, it typically signifies a solution for a specific purpose, problem, or task rather than a generalized solution

An ad-hoc lock is not a specific Java term, but in the context of the article [Synchronization in Java, Part 2: The synchronized keyword](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/java-thread-synchronization-synchronized-blocks-adhoc-locks) from which the examples are from, it simply means that the lock is taken from a dedicated object.

Answer (score 1):

It's not great terminology but it means that `synchronized` block isn't using the lock associated with the object (`this`) but some other object (specified in parenthesis).

All Java objects (logically) have a a lock associated with them. So you can declare methods like:

```
public synchronized void decrement() { /* Your code here. */ }
```

That means that method (and all similar methods) will be synchronised by each objects lock.
However there are many cases where you want to synchronise a method on one object with a lock on another.
Also declaring a whole method `synchronized` will mean the method is synchronised on entry and exit. Sometimes it's more efficient to some things before or after the critical section or otherwise suspend the lock during that section.

So declaring a method synchronised essentially means 'do not enter this method until you acquire a exclusive lock on the object in hand (`this`) and only release it after leaving the method.

Declaring `synchronized(lock) {/*...*/}` is similar but acquires the lock on `lock` on entry and holds it until exiting the block.